# Vedic devi shuktam or Tantrik? Can I choose any one?

Tags: devi, durga-saptasati

I found two Devi shuktams.
Vedic - `om aham rudrebhirvasubhiscaramyahamadityairuta visvadevaih। aham mitravaruhobha bibharmyahamindragni ahamasvinobha।।1।।`
Tantrik - `Ya devi sarva bhuteshu...`

I want to select one for reciting daily. Wondering which one to choose.
Let me know if anyone has knowledge on this area.

Comment: Both of them are Vedic.